# Tablas de multiplicar con php utilizando funciones

Tags: php, funciones, script

***Hola amigos tengo este codigo php lo que mi profesor me pide es que lo adapte a funciones y las utilize, por ejemplo ingresar este codigo a una funcion y pasarle el valor 'num' por parametros pero usando funciones espero que alguien me ayude porfavor gracias!***

````
$n=$_POST['num'];
if ($n<1 or $n>10) {
    echo "no has escrito un nůmero entre el 1 y el 10.";
    }
else {
     echo "<h4>Tabla del $n:</h4>";
     $i=1;
     while ($i<=10) {
           echo "$n x $i = ".$n*$i."<br/>";
           $i++;
           } 
     }
?>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo en tu pregunta buscas es crear una funcion donde le puedas pasar a la funcion el valor y este ejecute el resultado.
Si visitas el manual de PHP en la seccion de [FUNCIONES PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php) podras ver la estructura que debe tener una funcion creada por el usuario.

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
    <?php
    
    function bucle($n){
    
       if ($n<1 or $n>10) {
        echo "no has escrito un nůmero entre el 1 y el 10.";
        }
    else {
         echo "<h4>Tabla del $n:</h4>";
         $i=1;
         while ($i<=10) {
               echo "$n x $i = ".$n*$i."<br/>";
               $i++;
               }
         }
         }
    
bucle(6);
    
     ?>
```

cuando quieras ejecutar dicha funcion puedes llamarla en cualquier parte del codigo, tambien puedes hacerlo declarando una variable y pasandole esa variable a la funcion, ejemplo de ello:

```
<?php
$a = 4;
$b = 6;
$c = 8;
$d = 10;

bucle($a);
bucle($b);
bucle($c);
bucle($d);
```

Comment: Buenisimo jose, sabes que tuve en cuenta tu comentario y me resulto excelente! Mil gracias a la gente como tu le tengo mucho aprecio gracias!

Comment: Acepta la respuesta como solución a tu pregunta, estamos en contacto.